# Wrong values when calling function in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am new to Fortran and have to build an interface between C# and Fortran for that.
The passing of the argument from C# to Fortran works without problems, but the easier task, passing values inside the Fortran-code does not want to work...

When I want to pass parameters from one Fortran function to another, in this case from VdiFunctionRunner to TGA_810, the called function does not have the correct paramter-values.

This is a stripped down version of my code:

```
module VdiFunctionRunnerMain
  implicit none

  contains       
    integer function VdiFunctionRunner ()
      !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT, StdCall :: VdiFunctionRunner
      implicit none      

      CHARACTER (256) :: inXTGA, copyXTGA
      CHARACTER (256) :: ARRAY_810(10)

      copyXTGA = 'test'      
      nrReturnValues = tga_810(copyXTGA, 1)
      VdiFunctionRunner = nrReturnValues
      return
    end function VdiFunctionRunner

    integer function tga_810(xtga, testNr)
      character (256), intent(in)  :: xtga
      integer, intent(in) :: testNr
      tga_810=2
    end function tga_810

end module VdiFunctionRunnerMain
```

As you see the passed values should be 'test' and 1, but in the debugger I get only the first character of the array ('t') and testNr = 0.
I guess there is no error in writing the code, isn't it?
When the code is correct, does somebody know if this can be a compiler problem or something like that?

I am using the Intel 11 compiler.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you print the variables do you get the same values as the debugger shows?

Comment: I dont find anything wrong.   what's gonna happen if you have `print*,xtga` and `print*,testNr` inside the function tga_810?  also, you have to set the value of tga_810, like `tga_810=0`, in order to get return value (i dont think this is related to the problem you described tho)

Comment: I printed it in a file and get the following results:
 xtgaValue: t
 testNr = 0

I have written them out without any spaces, but there are some in the file. Maybe thats a part of the problem? I uploaded the file here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35743818/results.txt

Comment: i created test main program and compiled it with gfortran on cygwin.  I got 'test    ' (long string) and 1, as expected....  The only change I needed to make was to use `integer, external ::` instead of `external` for those vdiXXX (i asssumed they are functions).

Comment: I had bad experience of passing character from excel/vba to dll written in fortran on compaq/dec/microsoft fortran (dont remember who owned it back then).  i ended up not passing charater, and sticked to passing only reals and integers.  this was like ~10 years ago.  Does number come out right?  did you try explicitly pass some value for Nr?

Comment: sorry, you tested with nr=1...

Comment: I tested it with your changes, but then it does not compile anymore, because he doesn't recognize the pointers anymore.
I made a test with deleting everything, which is not directly related to the problem, but it still exist.
I will update my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Works fine on my system, provided you declare nrReturnValues as an integer. I am using Intel 12 however.

Comment: It also works fine with Intel 11.1.060 and 11.1.067. Can you check your exact version number?